# Who is the general depicted in the ending of Oda Nobuna no Yabou?

Tags: oda-nobuna-no-yabou

At the very end of episode 12, as if a teaser of season 2 (which apparently is not happening), a general (or daimyo) is shown behind her armies.

[image]

The light novels' storyline goes further than the anime, so who is she?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She is

> Shingen Takeda

based on the emblems. That is the emblem of the [Takeda Clan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeda_clan).

[image]

Also I read the novel and that is how she is depicted.